# How to change colour of react-bootstrap time picker?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-bootstrap, timepicker

I am using the Form Control time picker from react-bootstrap and want to change the drop down menu of the picker's colour from that blue, but can't seen to find the answer anywhere.

The time picker:

```
import { Form } from "react-bootstrap";

const TimePicker = () => {
  return (
    <Form.Control
      type="time"
      className="modalTextField"
      style={{ paddingRight: "6px" }}
    />
  );
};

export default TimePicker;
```

How it looks now:
[TimePicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWEH2.jpg)

Comment: Could you please share your code in sandbox or stackblitz?

Comment: Sure. Hope this helps. https://codesandbox.io/s/timepicker-z6wot?file=/src/App.js

Comment: The 'dropdown' which has shown is related to `HTML5` native component. It doesn't related to `bootstrap`. There isn't any pseudo element to select the `dropdown` for changing the 'dropdown's style.